# What is the density of the $m$'th element of a sorted vector of $n$ uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: density-function, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, order-statistics, extreme-value

$X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are independent and uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$. Sorting them yields a vector, whose first and last element have densities that are just the derivatives of products of CDFs.

As regards the second element i tried to use inclusion/exclusion, but the coefficients are only clear to me when $n \leq 3$. How to find the densities for large some $n$ and all $m$?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @CliffAB No,,,,

Comment: I've derived it before and I know it follows something like a beta distribution. I've actually written a silly R-package that allows you to take a sorted sample form a discrete distribution in linear time. Let me dig it up for you...

Comment: All of this are a certain beta distribution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order statistic for beta distribution](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156712/order-statistic-for-beta-distribution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with $n$ sorted uniform(0,1) distributions, denoted $u_1,..., u_n$ ($u_k$ is the $k^{th}$ order statistic). Or as I like to think of it for this problem, $n$ beta(1,1) distributions.

Now consider

$ \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} 
\frac{P(x - \epsilon < u_k < x + \epsilon) }{2\epsilon}$

which is, by definition, the pdf of $u_k$. To compute this probability for a given $\epsilon$, we note that there must $k-1$ independent uniform(0,1) variables less than $x - \epsilon$ and $n-k$ independent uniform(0,1) variables greater than $x+\epsilon$ and one uniform(0,1) variable that will fall in the interval $(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon)$. For a given $\epsilon$, this gives us probability

$\frac{(x-\epsilon)^{k-1} (1 -x +\epsilon)^{n-k} (2\epsilon)}{2\epsilon} 
\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}$.

Taking the limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, we get

$x^{k-1} (1 -x)^{n-k}
\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}$.

which is the pdf of a Beta($k, n-k+1$) distribution.

Interesting note: if you are interested in sampling from this, in general a Beta($a, b$) distribution is (relatively) slow to sample from due to an intractable integral. On the other hand, sampling from a Beta($1, b$) or a Beta($a, 1$) can be done in closed form. Turns out, sampling from $u_k | u_{k-1}$ will require sampling from a Beta($1, n - k+1$) distribution (and then linearly transforming), rather than a Beta($k, n$). As such, if $k$ is close to 1 or $n$, it is often much faster to sequentially sample $u_1$, $u_2|u_1$, ..., $u_k | u_{k-1}$ or likewise $u_n$, $u_{n-1} | u_n$, ..., $u_k | u_{k+1}$ then to directly sample $u_k$ from the given Beta($k, n$) distribution.

Comment: Can be found here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution

Comment: I don't recognize your expression as the CDF of any Beta distribution: it's proportional to the PDF of a Beta$(n-k+1,k+1)$ distribution--and that shows that it's incorrect.  The CDF is proportional to an incomplete Beta function.

Comment: @whuber: you are correct! It does turn out to be a [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution), but I had written the wrong beta distribution. Now deriving it on my own is somewhat confusing me: taking the derivative of the expression I wrote above does not seem to lead to a beta pdf, so I will work it on more on my own and update again when I am done.

Comment: One derivation is at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4684/919.  One place you have gone wrong is in providing an overly narrow characterization of the event $u_k\le x$: this includes all events where *at least* $k$ of the original data are less than or equal to $x$.  You should not also require that the remaining $n-k$ data exceed $x$!

Answer (score 2):

A non-rigorous derivation of the density function is given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4684/919.  It amounts to characterizing the density of $u_k$ near $x$ as the chance that $k-1$ of the $X_i$ are less than or equal to $x$, one of them is between $x$ and $x+dx$ (for infinitesimal $dx$), and the remainder exceed $x+dx$.  This is a multinomial probability equal to

$$f_k(x) = \binom{n}{k-1;\, 1;\, n-k} x^{k-1}(dx)^{1}(1-x-dx)^{n-k}.$$

Ignoring terms of order $(dx)^2$ and--if you prefer--expanding the multinomial coefficient, this is

$$f_k(x) = \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} x^{k-1} (1-x)^{n-k} dx.\tag{1}$$

That's the PDF of a Beta$(k,n+1-k)$ variable.  Notice that as $k=1,2,\ldots,n$, its parameters proceed $(1,n),(2,n-1), \ldots, (n,1)$: in particular, they never degenerate to $0$. (This is one quick check that the parameters are the correct ones and aren't one off due to some mistake of arithmetic.)

---

If you don't like infinitesimals, the same result can be derived beginning with the distribution function

$$F_k(x) = \Pr(u_k \le x).$$

In terms of the original $X_i$, the event $u_k \le x$ is that $k$ *or more* of the $X_i$ are less than or equal to $x.$  Since uniformity implies $\Pr(X_i\le x)=x$ and the $X_i$ are independent, this is a *Binomial* probability.  We may immediately write it as

$$F_k(x) = \sum_{j=k}^n \binom{n}{j} x^j(1-x)^{n-j}.$$

Differentiating ought to yield the density--and it does, with some work.  What is needed is to recognize that

$$\binom{n}{j+1}(j+1) = \frac{n!}{j!(n-j-1)!} = \binom{n}{j}(n-j).\tag{*}$$

Since $F_k$ is expressed as a finite sum, we may differentiate it term-by-term to produce

$$\eqalign{
f_k(x) & = \frac{d}{dx}F_k(x) = \sum_{j=k}^n \binom{n}{j} (jx^{j-1}(1-x)^{n-j}-(n-j)x^j(1-x)^{n-j-1})\\
&= \sum_{j=k-1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{j+1} (j+1)x^{j}(1-x)^{n-j-1}-\sum_{j=k}^n  \binom{n}{j}(n-j)x^j(1-x)^{n-j-1}\\
&= \sum_{j=k-1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{j+1} (j+1)x^{j}(1-x)^{n-j-1}-\sum_{j=k}^n  \binom{n}{j+1} (j+1)x^j(1-x)^{n-j-1}.\\
}$$

The relation $(*)$ was used in the last step.  The preceding step was merely a relabeling of the index $j$ to match up common expressions $x^j(1-x)^{n-j-1}$. **Every term but the first cancels out**, leaving

$$f_k(x) = \binom{n}{k} (k)x^{k-1}(1-x)^{n-k} = \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} x^{k-1} (1-x)^{n-k}.$$

This is identical to the original expression $(1)$.

Comment: Very nice! When I went back and tried to differentiate the CDF, I looked at the sum of $n$ choose $j$'s and got very scared (after realizing my mistake about there being $k$ **or more** $X_i...$)!